# How can I parse JSON with comma in android?

Tags: java, android, json

Im trying to parse JSON and my code is not working with one URL and it works with other. I think its the coma in question but I did not sure so please look at my code and help.
I tried to replace coma with dot in loop, but what i get is JSON Exception. And when I change the URL, there is no exception. Confusing...
This is not working URL: http://api.hnb.hr/tecajn/v1
And this is one I tested and it works: https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=e402c76fc8584a1c81849179f1277a74
While changed the URL I also changed the data, so its not the problem in writing..I guess

Here is my code for coma replacement:

```
 private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String coma = line.replaceFirst(",",".");
            sb.append(coma).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And the other part with URL and JSONArray:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        URLconnection urlConn = new URLconnection();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String url = "http://api.hnb.hr/tecajn/v1";
        //.........connection.........
        String response = urlConn.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + response);
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                arr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("values");

                for (int i = 0; i < article.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    header = c.getString("Valuta");

               }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: 216",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: *sigh*... Please use an http library with JSON support. Don't reimplement the wheel/copy code for HTTP and AsyncTask over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas aren't the issue. It's the very first character. One is a square bracket and the other is a curly one.

You therefore need to parse the first response as an Array rather than an Object

```
new JSONArray(response);
```

That being said, you therefore cannot use the same methods for both URLs

Comment: Did not notice that before.. -.-

Comment: No worries. For library's, you can try Retrofit or OkHttp. I think those are the more popular ones for Android

Comment: Will try. Thanks